# Sum t-scores from different tests?

Tags: t-test, mean

Is it possible to add for example t-scores from two different tests together and divide by two to get a mean t-score? I have t-scores from many subfactors that I would like to combine into a result for the main factor. Is there any problems with just combining t-scores and calculate mean? Any better way to do it?

I'm talking about a standardized t-score with mean 50.

Example: I have t-scores from different scales related to depression (sleep problem, apetite loss, anhedonia etc) and I want to get a score for how depressed that person is, so I can compare with other persons.

Comment: No - it is not as simple as that:  (a) the statistics are more complicated even if your different symptoms were independent and on equivalent scales and (b) they are not independent and you may want to weight the scales.

Comment: What is the real problem you want to solve? It would be better to ask about that.  It sounds to me like the problem you're trying to solve is `<X>`, and you're wondering
if `<Y>` is a good way to go about it. Is that fair? Because if your real question
is "`<X>`?" then I would suggest only asking about that. As its written right now, 
the question appears to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).